# As a Muslim manager, is it appropriate to organize a prayer room for customers?

Tags: business, masjid

Suppose I am a manager at a mall which is quite far from the main city (just an assumption). Due to the fact that coming at my mall would result in a lot of time being spent there due to its distance from the city, many people who observe prayers might find it difficult. As a Muslim, I make arrangements for a prayer room where my customers can offer Salaah easily.

That is no problem, but including a prayer room for Muslims might raise the eyebrows of people of other religions. Their religious sentiments might be hurt owing to the fact that the manager is a Muslim and he took account of the needs of Muslims only. Islam doesn't permit hurting the sentiments of other people, so should prayer rooms be built for them too? There is a problem that it might give rise to shirk over there.

Shirk is the worst sin, but rejecting their request might make it look that Muslims are unjust and do not treat others equally.

As a manager, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Salam, first I like to thank you for considering those things! That's impressive for me.

- Muslims respect all other religions and believe there is only one religion; each have been the continuation of the last one till Islam which is the last and the complete version.
- Christians,Jews,.. anyone who believes in one God is allowed to Muslim's mosques.
- A **Prayer Room** doesn't mean it's only there for Muslims, **anyone** can enter and pray in a peaceful environment!

Result: Don't fix it only for Muslims and just call it a Prayer Room, You can explain everyone it is also intended for people of other religions and I think it's even a good chance for others to learn about Islam by seeing their prayers or even sometimes hearing an scholar preaching.

Comment: that is good , but what if there are idols? some religions need idols at their praying place. Hinduism , Buddhism and even christians have the cross..

Answer (score 0):

Walekum Assalam. 
I suggest you to make one prayer hall with a separator 4 feet wall. The larger part should offer mats to sit or read or for salat . Smaller part offers a small library with most religions authenticated books including Quran in different languages. To maintain order, keep putting notice on board or on divider wall about salat timing, rules, disallow idols, facility you provide, dos and donts, and your contact in case anyone want to thank, request, complain or ask.